# Multiple SSL wildcards on 1 IP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, sni

Currently my server has 1 website running on https/ssl. The thing is when I enable a second vhost, also with https/ssl, the first website I have running is now using the ssl cert of the new website.

I have tried putting the two websites in a single vhost file, didn't work so I made 2 seperate files instead.

Here are my vhost config files:

(Naming them websiteZ and website Y because of alphabetical order they are in)

**vhost current running website .conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *.websiteZ.nl
Redirect 301 / https://websiteZ.nl
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.websiteZ.nl
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/websites/websiteZ.nl/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/websites/websiteZ.nl/public">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny   
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteZ.nl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteZ.nl/certificate.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteZ.nl/cabundle.crt 
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**new website with ssl .conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName websiteY.nl
    ServerAlias www.websiteY.nl
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/websites/websiteY.nl/public/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/websites/websiteY.nl/public/">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny   
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.websiteY.nl
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/websites/websiteY.nl/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/websites/websiteY.nl/public">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny   
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteY.nl/certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteY.nl/certificate.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/websiteY.nl/cabundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I looked up the SNI thing, but I think I'm missing something. The way I understand it is that I have to use NameVirtualHost to make it work.

The server is running on AWS ece2 with Ubuntu 16.04.2

The problem occurs when I type in terminal:

```
a2ensite websiteY.conf
```

When I do that websiteZ will lose it's https cert and will show a big red cross which says: NOT SECURE! When you click to proceed it links to websiteY

I am a little bit out of options, can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: What problem occurs when you type in terminal `a2ensite websiteY.conf`?

Comment: Thanks, i edited the post with: "When I do that websiteZ will lose it's https cert and will show a big red cross wich says: NOT SECURE! When you click to proceed it links to websiteY"

Comment: What **exactly** are you typing in your browser's address bar when trying to access websiteZ?

Comment: www.websiteZ.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter `www.websiteZ.nl` without `https`, the request will first be caught by

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *.websiteZ.nl
Redirect 301 / https://websiteZ.nl
</VirtualHost>
```

and therefore redirected to `https://websiteZ.nl`

Since none of your `:443` Virtual Hosts has neither `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` configured with `websiteZ.nl`, then the one from alphabetically first .conf file will be used, which is in this case the one with websiteY cert.

Comment: You sir, are a hero. I can't believe I missed this! It works.